# Logistic regression: Include a specific time variable to account for unexplained changes over time?

Tags: regression, logistic, marketing

I am measuring the effect of specific marketing activities on the likelihood to buy a product. The Marketing activities start on a specific date. All the products sold before this date a marked with a 0 - all the following ones consequently with a 1.

1. Do I need to include a separate variable due to the fact that the activity was introduced at a certain point of time (suddenly)? I heard that "event analysis" might help here but I did not find anything which helped me.
2. Do I need to control for other things my variables can`t capture (e.g. customer mindset) by including an extra variable over time in order to improve my results (something like a time trend)?

If yes, how would this work?

Comment: I think we should get more information about your case. What is your observation? Is it a specific transaction with timestamp containing many products or what?

Comment: Thank your for your response! Exactly! It is transaction data, which contains products with their specific selling date/time, price, brand and other specifics. Every product is a single observation. The marketing activities are then the base for new variables which are marked - with a 1 from a certain introduction date on - for every product. I hope this clarified my question.

Comment: I do not think it is valid to use normal logistic regression to this data. At least every receipt (transaction) contains many products, which means you have to take into account product wise correlation and serial correlation across time. You might want to try this class of generalized linear models (of which logistic regression is just one variation) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_generalized_linear_model